# Jquery add and remove class on form validation condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code, Which adds and remove class, The class is used to bring the next stage of the form, The form is step by step, Fill some fields validate on next and then fill others,

Button :

```
<input type="button" id="petOwnerStepOne" class="next" value="CONTINUE" />
```

The below code is not working.

```
$('#stepOne').click(function() {
  if ($('#FormID').valid()) {
    $( "#stepOne" ).addClass("next");
  } else {
    $( "#stepOne" ).removeClass("next");
  }
});
```

**The class adds but the form never goes to step two**, Without the above code and adding class to `<input class="next">` works fine.

**It goes to next step of the form by :**

```
  $(".next").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this)
    .parent()
    .next();
    $("#progressbar li")
    .eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs))
    .addClass("active");
    next_fs.show();
    current_fs.animate(
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        step: function(now, mx) {
          scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
          left = now * 50 + "%";
          opacity = 1 - now;
          current_fs.css({ transform: "scale(" + scale + ")" });
          next_fs.css({ left: left, opacity: opacity });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
          current_fs.hide();
          animating = false;
        },
        easing: "easeInOutBack"
      }
      );
  });
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: very unclear what you are asking, what do you mean all the code you show works but the form never goes to step two, where is the code for that ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Updated the question, Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$(".next").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",".next", function(){
```

because when your code is parsed the next class doesnt exist in DOM yet,common pitfall

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

please describe how the behavior of the form changes depending on the availability of the class "next". You can add you HTML code sample.
Are you debugging this code and "valid" method?
If you use google chrome you can put "debbuger" word before method valid() call and then see step by step what's happening. Or simple use console.log() in your code.